# pycharm project interpreter has requests but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, pycharm

**This is on Macos**

My project interpreter is located in:

**Pycharm>Preferences>Project Interpreter**

```
Python 3.7 (Evohome) ~ /Evohome/bin/python   ##### Evohome is my project name
Package       Version etc
certifi
chardet
idna
pip
requests
setuptools
urllib3
```

**if I run a script of:**

```
import requests
```

**The result of import requests is this error here.**

````
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

So, I can't get past the first bit after which I want to
import JSON


**if I run this code**
```
x = help("modules")
print(x)
exit(0)
```
**The Result from this is**
```
/Users/Jeff/venv/bin/python /Users/Jeff/Documents/Pycharm/EvoHome/Test1.py

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

```
*massive list of available modules*
```
Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose name or summary contain the string "spam".

None

Process finished with exit code 0
```
````

Comment: How did you install interpreter into your project directory?

Comment: I finally got past the request problem thanx it was all todo with pip3 still updating 2.7

Answer (score 0):

not sure which but one of these did it
pyenv install 3.7.6

pyenv global 3.7.6

pyenv version

echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc